# Interpreting mediation analysis results: non-significant Prop.Mediated

Tags: r, mediation

I am confused on how to interpret results of my mediation analysis where my `ACME` is significant (but very low by absolute value) but `Prop. Mediated` is not significant.
Here is the full code:

```
dt1 <- read.table(url('https://www.dropbox.com/s/6ahwnmxbottvxii/dt1.tsv?dl=1'))
head (dt1)
#    X      M     Y  conf1 conf2 conf3 conf4
# 1: 1 -0.074 6.583   Male 41.43  3420     2
# 2: 2  0.070 4.345   Male 40.40  2850     3
# 3: 2 -0.115 4.964 Female 37.10  4285     3
# 4: 1  0.012 6.232 Female 41.10  3380     2
# 5: 2  0.018 6.065 Female 41.00  3375     3
# 6: 2  0.012 5.542   Male 40.50  3980     3


# Step 1: total effect - association between X and Y
fit.total  <- lm(Y ~ X + conf1+conf2+conf3+conf4, data = dt1)
summary(fit.total)
# Call:
#   lm(formula = Y ~ X + conf1 + conf2 + conf3 + conf4, data = dt1)
# 
# Residuals:
#   Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
# -2.17008 -0.47772 -0.03215  0.45593  1.60839 
# 
# Coefficients:
#               Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
# (Intercept)  6.498e+00  1.369e+00   4.747 5.68e-06 ***
# X           -1.640e-01  8.782e-02  -1.868   0.0642 .  
# conf1Female  1.091e-01  1.262e-01   0.865   0.3889    
# conf2       -1.920e-02  3.608e-02  -0.532   0.5957    
# conf3        2.336e-05  1.178e-04   0.198   0.8431    
# conf4       -8.651e-02  7.822e-02  -1.106   0.2709    
# ---
# Residual standard error: 0.709 on 122 degrees of freedom
# Multiple R-squared:  0.04696, Adjusted R-squared:  0.007902 
# F-statistic: 1.202 on 5 and 122 DF,  p-value: 0.3121



# Step 2: association between X and mediator
fit.mediator <- lm(M ~ X + conf1+conf2+conf3+conf4, data = dt1)
summary(fit.mediator)
# Call:
#   lm(formula = M ~ X + conf1 + conf2 + conf3 + conf4, data = dt1)
# 
# Residuals:
#   Min        1Q    Median        3Q       Max 
# -0.217684 -0.061665  0.009555  0.058005  0.198306 
# 
# Coefficients:
#               Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)   
# (Intercept) -3.181e-02  1.659e-01  -0.192   0.8483   
# X            3.082e-02  1.065e-02   2.895   0.0045 **
# conf1Female -1.628e-02  1.530e-02  -1.064   0.2892   
# conf2       -2.730e-03  4.374e-03  -0.624   0.5337   
# conf3        1.334e-05  1.427e-05   0.935   0.3519   
# conf4        1.539e-02  9.482e-03   1.623   0.1072   
# ---
# Residual standard error: 0.08595 on 122 degrees of freedom
# Multiple R-squared:  0.0972,  Adjusted R-squared:  0.0602 
# F-statistic: 2.627 on 5 and 122 DF,  p-value: 0.02714



# Step 3: effect of the mediator on Y:
fit.dv <- lm(Y ~ X + M + conf1+conf2+conf3+conf4, data = dt1)
summary(fit.dv)
# Call:
#   lm(formula = Y ~ X + M + conf1 + conf2 + conf3 + conf4, data = dt1)
# 
# Residuals:
#   Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
# -2.06212 -0.48447  0.02689  0.46917  1.52979 
# 
# Coefficients:
#               Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
# (Intercept)  6.438e+00  1.339e+00   4.807 4.44e-06 ***
# X           -1.067e-01  8.882e-02  -1.202   0.2318    
# M           -1.860e+00  7.306e-01  -2.546   0.0122 *  
# conf1Female  7.883e-02  1.240e-01   0.636   0.5262    
# conf2       -2.428e-02  3.536e-02  -0.687   0.4936    
# conf3        4.818e-05  1.156e-04   0.417   0.6776    
# conf4       -5.789e-02  7.734e-02  -0.748   0.4557    
# ---
# Residual standard error: 0.6936 on 121 degrees of freedom
# Multiple R-squared:  0.09542, Adjusted R-squared:  0.05056 
# F-statistic: 2.127 on 6 and 121 DF,  p-value: 0.05497


# Step 4: mediation analysis:
require(mediation)

res.med <- mediate(fit.mediator, fit.dv, treat = 'X', mediator = 'M', boot = T, sims = 1000)
summary(res.med)
# Causal Mediation Analysis 
# Nonparametric Bootstrap Confidence Intervals with the Percentile Method
# 
# Estimate 95% CI Lower 95% CI Upper p-value   
# ACME            -0.0573      -0.1153        -0.01   0.002 **
# ADE             -0.1067      -0.2969         0.09   0.286   
# Total Effect    -0.1640      -0.3596         0.04   0.100 . 
# Prop. Mediated   0.3494      -1.1946         3.32   0.102   
# ---
# Sample Size Used: 128 
# Simulations: 1000
```

From the first steps, I initially concluded that I do have mediation effect (I see significant association `M ~ X` and borderline significant `Y ~ X`, and the latter one disappears when I add mediator - `Y ~ X + M`). But I'm not sure how to interpret results of actual `mediate()` call. Would be very grateful for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could state something like this and it should be good enough for the reviewers:

> The indirect effect of X on Y via M is statistically significant (ab =
> -0.057, 95%CI = [-0.11, -0.01]). The proportion mediated is (-0.057/-0.164) = 0.349.

You may want to crank the number of bootstrap repetitions up to 5,000 or 10,000 though.

As a side note, I rarely ever see proportion mediated get reported (but this is an informative effect size and you should still report it!). The reason the 95% CI for Prop. Mediated is so large is because your sample size is rather small (N=128). Based on various simulation results (e.g., Lee et al. 2015; MacKinnon et al., 1995), Prop. Mediated do not really stabilize until N is larger than 500.

- Lee, S., Lei, M. K., & Brody, G. H. (2015). Constructing confidence intervals for effect size measures of an indirect effect. Multivariate behavioral research, 50(6), 600-613.
- MacKinnon, D. P., Warsi, G., & Dwyer, J. H. (1995). A simulation study of mediated effect measures. Multivariate behavioral research, 30(1), 41-62.